# store foreach results in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, ebay-api

im trying to store values from foreach loop in array

```
$result_itemid = array();
foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
   $itemid = $item->itemId;
   $title = $item->title;
   $result_itemid[] .= $itemid;
}

print_r($result_itemid);
```

i try it and it works: output

> [0] => 7048668, [1] => 5651831 etc..

but i want more option like:

> [0][0] => 7048668 [0][1] => Black
>   -- [1][0] => 5651831 [1][1] => white

Thank you :)

Comment: `$result_itemid[] = [$itemid, $title];` Make an effort, read a manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result_itemid = [];
$ids = [];
$titles = [];
foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
   $ids[] = $item->itemId;
   $titles[] = $item->title;
}

array_multisort($ids, $titles);

foreach( $ids as $i => $id ) {
    $result_itemid[] = [ $id , $titles[$i] ];
}

print_r($result_itemid);
```

Comment: thank you but dont work, do you have any more ideas ?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\store\MySample.php

Comment: @Niv_H make sure you use `=` and not `.=`

Comment: yes its works, the error was in other line.. im sorry, 1 more thing how can i sort the result in alphabetical order (with the id values)?

Comment: cant do that .. `"$result_itemid[] = [$itemid, $title];"` must be in the first foreach, i didnt post the all code